# num++ marked as syntax error in python - why?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, syntax-error

Consider the following xml file (lieferungen2.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lieferungen>
    <artikel id="1">
       <name>apple</name>
       <preis >2</preis>
       <lieferant>Friedman</lieferant>
    </artikel>
</lieferungen>
```

With the following code, I wanted to print "apple" to the command line:

```
import xml.dom.minidom 

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse("lieferungen2.xml")

a = dom.getElementsByTagName("artikel")

num=0


while(True):

    if a[0].childNodes[num].nodeName != "name":
        num++
    else:
        break

print(a[0].childNodes[num].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
    num++
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To me this syntax looks perfectly fine? What's wrong here?

Comment: You should use `num += 1` instead

Comment: It's marked as a syntax error because it's not Python syntax.

Comment: You can also refer to stackoverflow.com/questions/3654830/why-are-there-no-and-operators-in-python to have an idea why increment operators are not a part of Python.

Answer (score 0):

num++ is not valid Python code, it would be like this

```
num += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not support `x ++` to increase a variable by one.

Instead, you have to do `x += 1`.

So your code would be:

```
if a[0].childNodes[num].nodeName != "name":
    num += 1
else:
    break
```